# Whether it is not necessary to use the `this.` keyword for variables within c# class?

Tags: c#

[image: facade]

In C# there is concept of static and instance variables.

Static variables are shared by all instances.

In the code snapshot from above, an instance field _bigClass is created. In the constructor and other methods, this is instantiated and it's methods are invoked. My question is - why has the user not used `this.`_bigClass? I'm trying to understand whether it is not necessary to use the `this.` keyword to access variables within c# class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it's not required or necessary since that variable is not marked as `static`, compiler can identify that it's a instance member and not a static one.

In other case, where your instance variable and constructor variable names are same, you can use `this` to specify the instance member explicitly like

```
public ClassA(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply because you do not need to.

If there is a member `_bigClass` (and there is not a local variable `_bigClass` whose name would "shadow" it), then just writing `_bigClass` is enough.

Writing `this._bigClass` would be the same.

That's it.